# Using DeX with two external Monitors?

Tags: hdmi, emui, samsung-dex

I would like to replace my desktop computer with an android phone.
I only do word processing (in google docs) and internet browsing (chrome), so I figured the processing power of a new phone should be enough for that.
However, I like to write on one screen, while I read pdfs or research websites on another screen.

I have two HDMI monitors.

Can I use Samsung DeX or android desktop mode for this?

What should I look out for, when buying a phone or a suitable docking station? (I haven't seen ones with two HDMIs yet)

Comment: I don't think that this can work with HDMI because the phone can only handle one HDMI connection. With DisplayPort monitors there might be a chance as it is possible to daisy chain monitors (Phone -> Monitor1 -> Monitor2). But I don't know if Samsung Dex mode can handle multiple monitors. Have you asked Samsung support about connecting two monitors using Dex?

Comment: I have seen usb-c hubs with two hdmi outputs, but i am not sure if any phone can display two desktops using this. I am not bent on using DeX, android desktop or any other solution would be fine, as long as it works. Will contact samsung and let you know what they say.

Comment: I'm curious, what does Samsung say about this?

Comment: At the time the official answer was that it was not supported, but that was one year ago. Haven't followed up with them since I ended up buying a notebook. However there are some workarounds like this: https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/samsung-dex/dual-monitor-output-for-dex/td-p/14136930